# How to subscribe to child route params and use result to run another service?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular-router, angular-router-params

I'm trying to have the following scenario working; I have a screen, lets call it `AdminComponent`, which has two sidebars and a `router-outlet` which displays the selected item route.

```
<div class="console container">
    <div class="sidebar-left"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-right"></div>
    <div class="outlet-container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

On `left-sidebar` I render multiple links which change the route to `/admin/:id`; I use a simple `get` service to fetch the data I need for each item to render the links.

On `right-sidebar` I'm trying to subscribe to the route parameters so that when the value changes, I can also run a different service fetch the data for the specific `:id` which will contain an array of `action-items` for the item selected on the `left-sidebar`.

The last part is what I'm having troubles with since I don't see the subscription to the parameters working; I have tried using:

```
this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe()
```

But this throws an error when I'm on the parent route `admin/`, it only works if I navigate directly to `admin/1` for example. I need to subscribe to the route change so I can render the items on the right sidebar but I don't really know how to approach it at this point.

Hope it is clear enough, any other details that might help I can provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is listen for any navigation and then get the queryParams like so

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

// ... 

constructor( 
  public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
  public router: Router
) {}

// ...

ngOnInit() {
   this.listenForRouteChange();
}

listenForRouteChange() {
   this.router.events
     .pipe(filter(x => x instanceof NavigationEnd))
     .subscribe(result => {
       // you could do two things here, if you know that you are only ever going
       // to have the single param you can do this
       let url = result.urlAfterRedirects.split('/');
       let params = url[url.length - 1]; 

       // or if you want to be more precise call this function
       this.getRouteParams();
     });
}

getRouteParams() {
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams
     .subscribe(result => {
       let id = result.id;
     });
}
```

Comment: I'll try this out and give an update; by the way, in this case, after I get the params in `listenForRouteChange()` could I also chain another service that will fetch data based on the param I just received?

Comment: @IvanS95 yeah you can do whatever you want in there

Comment: I tried this and I only get an `undefined` result unless I navigate directly to the child route; so if I enter the URL `admin/1` I get the instance of the navigation, but if I first load `admin/` to then click a link to `admin/1` I just get undefined :/

Comment: nevermind, must have done something wrong, it's working like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help!